# Is this a better way for Fibonacci Series with Recursion?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Where ever I see Recursive Fibonacci Series everyone tell that

```
a[i] = fib(i - 1) + fib( i - 2)
```

But it can also be solved with

```
a[i] = fib(i - 1) + a[i-2] // If array 'a' is a global variable.
```

If array 'a' is a global Variable, then a[i-2] will be calculated when it is calculating for a[i-2];

It can be solved with below program in java..

```
public class Fibonacci {

    public static int maxNumbers = 10;
    public static double[] arr = new double[maxNumbers];

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        arr[0] = 0;
        arr[1] = 1;

        recur(maxNumbers - 1);
    }

    public static double recur(int i)
    {
        if( i > 1)
        {
            arr[i] = recur(i - 1) + arr[i - 2];
        }

        return arr[i];
    }
}
```

Further more, complexity is also less when compared with original procedure. Is there any disadvantage of doing this way?

Comment: You are limiting yourself this way. You can just store the two previous values of the Fibonacci number and not every single one, since you only need the previous two to calculate the next one. As to your original question the array method is superior to the recursive one since it takes less time and less memory to compute than the recursive version.

Comment: Congratulations, you've rediscovered [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: The best way is to use iteration, not recursion. Iteration is much faster and simpler to implement in a reasonable time.

Comment: The best way is to use the formula, which is (phi^i + theta^i)/sqrt(5) where phi and theta are the golden ratio and its conjugate, respectively.

Comment: Ok I take that back.  Because the golden ratio is irrational, the precision in computing it is a problem.  Precision becomes a problem as i increases.

Comment: @PeterLawrey A memoized recursive solution would end up averaging O(1) for every argument it already has visited while an iterative solution will do at best O(n).

Comment: @Sylwester Is complexity of above alg O(n) ?

Comment: Yes. The reason is that when you do recur(5) a second time you already have arr[5] but you don't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have done the first step for [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) calculation of Fibonacci, idea of DP is to avoid redundant calculations, and your algorithm achieve its goal.

A "classic" Bottom-Up DP Fibonacci implementation is filling the elements from lower to higher:

```
arr[0] = 0
arr[1] = 1
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2]
```

(Optimization could be storing `curr,last` alone, and modifying them at each iteration.

Your approach is basically the same in principle.

---

As a side note, the DP approach to calculate Fibonacci is taking `O(n)` time, where there is even more efficient solution with exponential of the matrix:

```
1 1 
1 0
```

The above holds because you use the fact that

```
1     1               F_{n+1}                1*F{n+1} + 1*F{n}           F_{n+2}
               *                       =                          =                         
1     0               F_{n}                  1*F{n+1} + 0*F{n}           F_{n+1}
```

Using [exponent by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) on the above matrix, this can be solved in `O(logn)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the nth fibonacci number you could do this:

```
static double fib(double prev, double curr, int n) {

    if(n == 0)
        return curr;

    return fib(curr, prev+curr, n-1);

}
```

Initial conditions would be `prev = 0`, `curr = 1`, `n = maxNumbers`.  This function is tail recursive because you don't need to store the return value of the recursive call for any additional calculations.  The initial stack frame gets reused (which saves memory) and once you hit your base case the value that's returned is the same value that would be returned from every other recursive call.

Comment: Please elaborate on the relation to a function taking a single natural number `n` as a parameter, returning the `n`th fibonacci number.

Comment: This is a good way to get something like iteration, but using recusion to do it.

Comment: The function parameters keep track of the two terms you need to calculate the next term (prev, curr) and the number of terms left to calculate (n).  `prev` and `curr` are used instead of maintaining an array of calculated values.  Since this function is recursive and not iterative, I need to keep track of these values in the function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can also code using two recursive function but as the same value is calculating over again and again so all You can do a dynamic programming approach where You can store the value and return it where need.Like this one in C++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int dp[100];

int fib(int n){

   if(n <= 1)
     return n;

   if(dp[n]!= -1)
     return dp[n];

   dp[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);

   return dp[n];

}

int main(){

   memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));

   for(int i=1 ;i<10 ;i++)
    cout<<fib(i)<<endl;

}
```

Comment: No need for 1000 elements. Even with 64 bit signed integers the maximum fibonaccinumber without overflowing the result would be the 92nd.

Answer (score 1):

By using an array like you do you only recalculate one of the two branches (the longest one in each iteration) ending up with a O(n) complexity.

If you were to keep track on how large fibonacci number you have caclulated earlier you can use that and produce O(max(n-prevn, 1)). Here is an altered version of your code that fills the array from bottom to i if needed:

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static final int maxNumbers = 93; // fib(93) > Long.MAX_VALUE 
    public static long[] arr = new long[maxNumbers];
    public static int calculatedN = 0;

    public static long fib(int i) throws Exception
    {
        if( i >= maxNumbers )
            throw new Exception("value out of bounds"); 

        if( calculatedN == 0 ) {
            arr[0] = 0L;
            arr[1] = 1L;
            calculatedN = 1;
        }

        if( i > calculatedN ) {
           for( int x=calculatedN+1; x<=i; x++ ){
             arr[x] = arr[x-2] + arr[x-1];
           }
           calculatedN = i;
        }

        return arr[i];
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
       try {
        System.out.println(fib(50)); // O(50-2)
        System.out.println(fib(30)); // O(1)        
        System.out.println(fib(92)); // O(92-50)
        System.out.println(fib(92)); // O(1)        
       } catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

I changed double to long. If you need larger fibonacci numbers than fib(92) I would change from long to Biginteger.

Answer (score 0):

This is only step from non recursive version:
https://gist.github.com/vividvilla/4641152

General this partially recursive approach looks incredibly messy